# Modify the content of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, transform

I would like to transform/modify the content of dataframe. Basically I have a dataframe like below:

```
        bins      pval
1   2L:1:150 0.9224217
2 2L:151:300 0.9478824
3 2L:301:450 0.9671139
4 2L:451:600 0.9280847
5 2L:601:750 0.9698584
6 2L:751:900 0.9725379
```

And I would like to transform/modify into another dataframe like this, where I split the content of my "bins" column (first row) into 150 rows containing the same values. And so on for the second row.

```
    chr  pos    pval
1   2L   1 0.9224217
2   2L   2 0.9224217
3   2L   3 0.9224217
4   2L   4 0.9224217
5   2L   5 0.9224217
...
150  2L   150 0.9224217
151  2L   151 0.9478824
152  2L   152 0.9478824
153  2L   153 0.9478824
etc...
```

Any help much appreciated,

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer which may be, I fear, too specific and may need generalization. Assume the first dataframe is named "df1":

data.frame(chr="2L", pos=1:(150*NROW(df1)), pval=rep(df1$pval, each=150) )

Argument recycling should make the "chr" long enough without a rep function.

Edit in reply to comment. If the repeat length is always 150 then the fix is easy:

```
data.frame(chr = rep(substr(df1$bins, 1,2), each=150), 
           pos = 1:(150*NROW(df1)), 
           pval = rep(df1$pval, each=150) )
```

Comment: This would work if "chr" is always "2L", however I do have bins such as 3R:1:150, 4L:1:150, etc.... So the column 'chr' is not a constant.

Comment: This runs perfectly in about 2 or 3 min with a data.frame of 1 million rows. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at a more generalized answer that could be made more efficient. I couldn't find an easy way to convert from a `factor` to `numeric` while retaining the levels in the new `numeric` column. Regardless, this should work and can support different values for the "chr" column and different numbers of rows:

```
library(plyr)

df <- read.table(textConnection("        bins      pval
1   2L:1:150 0.9224217
2 2L:151:300 0.9478824
3 2L:301:450 0.9671139
4 2L:451:600 0.9280847
5 2L:601:750 0.9698584
6 2L:751:900 0.9725379
"), header = TRUE)

#Split bins
df.split <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$bins), ":")), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE ))

colnames(df.split) <- c("chr", "low", "high")

df.split$low <- as.numeric(as.character(df.split$low))
df.split$high <- as.numeric(as.character(df.split$high))

#Attach the pval from original df
df.split$pval <- df[, 2]

df.new <- adply(df.split, 1, summarise, pos = (low - 1) + seq(low:high))
df.new <- df.new[, c(1, 5, 4)]
```

Comment: The proper factor to numeric coercion is an R-FAQ: num <- as.numeric(as.character(fac))

Comment: @Dwin - that is indeed much simpler!

Comment: I have tested this code with my data.frame which contain more than 1 million rows, and it is still running...

Comment: @Benoit - if you always know that you are repeating 150x, then DWin's answer will be faster. I'll look a bit more into what is taking so long, I imagine it is the call to `adply`

Answer (score 0):

Firs import with stringsAsFactors = FALSE in order not to get factors (or use Chase answer to convert to character):

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("        bins      pval
1   2L:1:150 0.9224217
2 2L:151:300 0.9478824
3 2L:301:450 0.9671139
4 2L:451:600 0.9280847
5 2L:601:750 0.9698584
6 2L:751:900 0.9725379
"), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now, the rest:

```
split <- strsplit(df$bins, ":")
df$chr <- sapply(split, "[[", 1)
reps <- sapply(split, function(el) diff(as.numeric(el[2:3]))+1) 
df[rep(1:nrow(df), reps), c("chr", "pval")] 

      chr      pval
1      2L 0.9224217
1.1    2L 0.9224217
1.2    2L 0.9224217
1.3    2L 0.9224217
1.4    2L 0.9224217
1.5    2L 0.9224217
1.6    2L 0.9224217
1.7    2L 0.9224217
1.8    2L 0.9224217
1.9    2L 0.9224217
1.10   2L 0.9224217
...
```